# How knockout ko.mapping.fromJs() handles the $ref nodes in Json

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

The Json which came from the server contains some refs like this:

```
[
    {
        id:"1",
        name:"Mehran",
        supervisor:
        {
            id:"2",
            name: "Ayaz",
            supervisor: null
        }
    },
    {
        id:"3",
        name:"Ramin",
        supervisor: {$ref="1"}
    }
]
```

How does knockout mapping's `fromJS` or `fromJson` interpret this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON in your example is **invalid**. It is unexpected token `{$ref="1"}`.
Argument for `fromJS` function should be the valid JSON
and argument for function `fromJson` should be a string representation of valid JSON value.

Knockout will throw exeption in both cases. You should pass full object instead of reference

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? Nothing about the main question here.