# How to use $ref from JSON.NET with knockout

Tags: json, knockout.js, json.net

I have some hierarchical JSON being passed from the server, and when I serialize it to pass to my Knockout ViewModel, it returns $id and $ref properties. I understand this is to avoid infinite loop issues. The problem is, I need to access that actual information inside my knockout code. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: It would help if you extend your question a bit. Include some code, things you've tried and why they didn't work, etc.

Comment: Check out the JSON in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799385/how-knockout-ko-mapping-fromjs-handles-the-ref-nodes-in-json) for an example of the $ref value to which I refer. The question is, is there any way to work with this in knockout?